# How can we bring a closed question to immediate moderator attention?

Tags: support, moderation

How can I bring the question for reopening to moderators attention?

As if my question is to be closed we used to flag a question and it gets immediate moderator attention, how can a user whom got closed question remind the moderator to reopen the question?

Comment: When you copy [content from other websites](https://www.linux.com/home/81-applications/8261-note-to-new-linux-users-no-antivirus-needed). Attribute them. This is not acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can flag the question again and ask for it to be reopened.
2. You can open a question on [Meta Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/) about it (which you did).

Comment: ♦ what can a new user do whom has 1 reputation and he cant even participate in meta without 5 reputations!

Comment: @vikki: You only need a single upvote on a question to get that reputation. If you are unable to make that happen, your issues lie elsewhere.

Comment: consider this situation,the user needs to clarify his/her one and only question and he/she asks a question and get his/her  closed,if he needs to get up voted he needs either he/she may need to ask another question and need to get the question one up vote,if an user whom don't wish to question anymore and needs clarification for his/her question how can he/she do it?and another thing suppose if the question with -3 votes will took longtime to up vote and normally people wont seek interest in viewing the closed question and people usually feel shy to up vote the down voted question!

Comment: @vikki: What you describe is very frustrating indeed and I fully understand that that is not very desirable. However, please note that we have **far** more potential spammers than we have users in that situation. The reputation limit to participate on meta (as well as chat) is primarily intended to prevent spam.

Comment: How can we flag a question again and ask for it to be reopened?  I see no option to do so anywhere, on any closed question.